# Creating a wider fermata

Tags: lilypond, fermata

In LilyPond, how can I create a wide fermata that spans over several notes?

[image: fermata over several notes]

This is from Franz Schubert's [*Winterreise*](https://imslp.org/wiki/Winterreise,_D.911_(Schubert,_Franz)), No. 9 "Irrlicht", measure 39.

Comment: +1. Are you sure it's not a slur plus a badly placed staccato dot?

Comment: Have you encountered this or rather do you think you need it? The only way you can "hold" consecutive notes like that with a fermata (on the piano) is if you play them with the pedal. However, even then, you need only indicate pedal down with the first note and put the fermata over the *last* note.

Comment: @jeanas:  Or just a slur plus a badly placed fleck on the scanner.

Comment: If you look at Schubert's [manuscript](https://imslp.org/wiki/Winterreise,_D.911_(Schubert,_Franz)) you'll see that's the way he always wrote fermatas. There's no special significance of the wide fermata. However the manuscript does leave open exactly which of the four notes gets the fermata. Musically only the highest note makes sense and that's the note that some editions put the fermata on.